# Android traverse the raw folder

Tags: android

I am a novice programmer,and encounter a problem in the development of an Android application.I have a subfolder raw under the folder res, now ,i want to traverse the folder raw and get  files' name and path  in the folder. who can help me?

There are some MP3 files in the raw folder ,and i want to list of their name and get their path for use VideoView to play it.  poor English, forgive me，thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to get a list of files shipped with the app, move the files in the assets folder.

For example : if you create a folder in the assets folder called 'video' then you can retrieve a string array with the filenames like this :

```
String[] filesInAssets = getResources().getAssets().list("video");
```

I don't see a solution for reading the files under the res folder.

Comment: but i can't get the file path in 'video'  ,i want to get files' path so that i can use the method videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));  Thank you for your patience to answer!